# Remove specifically positioned character from string in javascript moving from the back

Tags: javascript

I was trying to figure out a way to remove a specifically positioned character within a string from the back. Here is my scenario:

Right now, if I have strings like:

```
'RX8567' 'A8532' '18256'
```

I want to remove the first 8 that I see in each string. However, I want to go about this from the back of the string if possible, since the I'm not sure how many alphanumeric characters will be in front of the string, but from the back, I know that it will always be the 4th character. So basically, if "8" is the fourth character of the string moving from the back, I want to remove it. I somewhat figured out how to do it from the front:

```
    var string = 'A8532'            
    var string = string.slice(0,1) + string.slice(2);
```

and this should result in I believe

```
'A532'
```

But this only works if 8 comes immediately after the A. Is there a different/simpler method to do this and moving from the back of the string for the scenarios described? Thank You in advance!

Comment: So just match the 8 and remove it. Why use substrings? RegEx would be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var code = 'RX8567';
//if '8' is the fourth character of the string moving from the back remove it
if (code.slice(-4, -3) === '8') {
    code = code.slice(0, -4) + code.slice(-3);
}
```

`code.slice(0, -4)` will give you all, but last four characters

`code.slice(-3)` will give you last three characters

---

Another solution would be to use regexp:

```
var code = 'RX8567';
code = code.replace(/(?:^(.*)8(.{3})$)/, '$1$2');
```

`(?:` creates non-capturing group (whole expression)

`^` matches the beginning of string

`(.*)` matches any number of characters (group $1 in replace string)

`8` matches your "8" character

`(.{3})` matches three characters (any) (group $2 in replace string)

`$` matches the end of the string

`)` closing bracket for the group from beginning of regexp

---

If you will process *a lot of* such codes then the first solution can be several times faster.

Comment: Your solution using regexp doesn't work if the code is `RX85678`

Comment: @silentw The question says "but from the back, I know that it will always be the 4th character." and "So basically, if "8" is the fourth character of the string moving from the back, I want to remove it." and my regexp removes the fourth character counting from the back if that's a "8".

Comment: @Keammoort this helped me a lot. very simple.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
var removeEight = function removeEight(code) {
    let eightIndex = code.indexOf('8');
    return eightIndex === -1 ? code : code.slice(0, eightIndex) + code.slice(eightIndex + 1);
};

var codes = ['RX8567', 'A8532', '18256'];

for (let i = 0; i < codes.length; ++i) {
    console.log(codes[i] + ' becomes ' + removeEight(codes[i]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function replace8(value){

  // Get the 4th from last character in the string
  var char4 = value.charAt(value.length - 4);
  
  // If that character is the string '8', remove it, otherwise, do nothing
  value =  char4 === '8' ? value.replace(value[value.length - 4], '') : value;
  console.log(value);
}

replace8('RX8567');
replace8('A9532');
replace8('18258');
```